# How can I check if 2 columns are identical on SAS?

Tags: database, sas

I have a big dataset obtained from a joint operation, and I would like to check if 2 character variables (let's call them var_1 and var_2) are the same or not. Is there any SAS function that I can use for it?

Comment: Are the two variables in the same data set? If so, it is as simple as: check = (var_1 = var_2);

Comment: Yes they are in the same dataset, I'm pretty sure is not a difficult task it's just that I'm getting start with SAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you can use this as a template. Feel free to ask :-)

```
data have;
input var_1 var_2;
datalines;
1 1
1 2
2 2
2 1
;

data want;
   set have;
   check = (var_1 = var_2);
run;
```

Result:

```
var_1 var_2 check 
1     1     1 
1     2     0 
2     2     1 
2     1     0
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, how can I sum all the 1's in the check column?

Comment: A running sum or do you just want the final sum?

Comment: If possible only the final sum of the 1's